# Choosing boundry conditions for PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

This is a rather general question.

Many books on PDEs tend to focus on modeling the PDE based on some physics problem but they don't really explain if given a PDE and we are supposed to choose which boundary conditions to impose on that PDE such that the PDE has a unique solution and how to do that.

I admit I'm asking this question because I was working on a specific problem. To illustrate my point I'll post that problem as well:

> Given the following boundary conditions and PDEs, assign the conditions to the PDEs such that they each have a unique solution:
> ([Original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncB2s.png))
>
> 1. $\Psi(t,t)=\sin t$, $\left.\dfrac{\partial\Psi(x,t)}{\partial x}\right|_{x=t} - \left.\dfrac{\partial\Psi(t,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{y=t}=t$.
> 2. $\Psi(t,-t)=\sin t$, $\left.\dfrac{\partial\Psi(x,-t)}{\partial x}\right|_{x=t} - \left.\dfrac{\partial\Psi(t,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{y=-t}=t.$
> 3. $\Psi\big(\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi)\big)=\sin(2\phi)$

> 1. $\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y} -2\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$
> 2. $\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x^2} -2 \dfrac{\partial\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y} +2\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$
> 3. $\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x^2} +3 \dfrac{\partial\Psi(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y} +2\dfrac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$

Now the problem actually requires me to assign first the boundary conditions and then solve the PDEs: if I could assign the boundary conditions after having determined the formal structure of the solution, I could try a brute force approach, but it is not so. I assume there is a general way of choosing boundary conditions basing on the classification of PDEs (such as conditions valid only  for parabolic or elliptic or hyperbolic PDEs): am I right?